# PictureBoxes and Zorder [.NET]

Tags: .net, picturebox

I have difficulties with showing multiple (up to 5) pictureboxes on top each other, but able to see all of them. Only first and last will show up. I show them from bottom to top, set their locations correctly and using BringToFront() function. Does anybody have a solution (if any)? Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what the actual problem is; the following code adds 5 stacked `PictureBox`es to a form, and configures them so they are all visible.

```
private void AddStackedPictureBoxes()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();

        pb.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(i * 50, i * 50, i * 50);
        pb.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;

        pb.Location = new Point(i * 10, i * 10);
        pb.Size = new Size((5 - i) * 20, (5 - i) * 20);

        Controls.Add(pb);

        pb.BringToFront();
    }
}
```

Perhaps that will give you some insight into why you are having problems.

For example, if you call `BringToFront()` before the control is added to the form, it won't have any effect.

Comment: thanks, the problem was that I added them *after* using BringToFront() ... didn't realized until now (bad habit from VS Form Desinger - set all properties, then add to panel/form etc.)

Comment: You also need to make sure your pictureboxes are added to the same control. I was going crazy wondering why a picturebox added to the main form wouldn't go under a picturebox added to a panel. Whoops!

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to set background color to transparent on each of them.

and as Daniel said, BringToFront() only works if the control is already on a form.

Comment: well I don't know why I should do that (with transparent color). I draw pictures with no transparent regions/areas whatsoever.

Comment: Well I assumed the reason you'd stack them is so that you can have a layered effect.